# Cant instantiate multi-sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I can't seem to load a sprite runtime.

I have a main grid object, on the grid I have a TerrainDrawer component.

The code for the script :

```
void Start()
{
    Sprite[] myFruit = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Sprites/multisprite");

    foreach(var sprite in myFruit)
    {
        print("sprite : " + sprite.name);
    }

    /*var spritePath = "Sprites/225835_hyptosis_tile-art-batch-1";
    //GameObject go = new GameObject();*/

    SpriteRenderer renderer = gameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    renderer.sprite = myFruit[0];


    //renderer.sprite = Resources.Load(spritePath , typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
}
```

The sprite that I'm wanting to use:

[image]
[image]

When I start up my game, I get this error :

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>   TerrainDrawer.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/TerrainDrawer.cs:21)

I have a strong feeling that my problem is with the path to the sprite, but now matter what I try, I can't get it loaded up.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load from *Resources* in code there must exist a folder named Resources with that sprite in it. You are basically loading in an empty array and that is why you get an out of range error.

[Take a look at this page from the docs.](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/resources-folder)

Hope this helps!

Comment: You, sire. Are my hero. Thanks!